# Preloading video used in the html 5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I was given the following code to use video in a canvas, but I was wondering if it is possible to preload the video. Fully download, and play it when finished. Even better, how about progressively download at certain percentage, say 80%.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html land="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Using video in the canvas tag</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function init(){
        var can = document.getElementById('canvas1');
        var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

        var vid = document.createElement('video');
        vid.src = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/Anthropoides_paradisea1.ogg';
        vid.autoplay = true;
        vid.loop = true;

        setInterval(function() {
            ctx.drawImage(vid, 0, 0);
        }, 60);
    }
</script>

</head>


<body onLoad="init();">
    <canvas id="canvas1" width="500" height="500"></canvas>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Ah I'd be very interested in the same concept, but for music files instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you would be interested in the `canplaythrough` event. This fires when it looks like enough has loaded that if played back at the current rate it will be completely loaded before it is done playing.

```
var vid, ctx;

function play() {
    vid.play();
    setInterval(function() {
        ctx.drawImage(vid, 0, 0);
    }, 60);
}

function init() {
    var can = document.getElementById('canvas1');
    ctx = can.getContext('2d');
    vid = document.createElement('video');
    vid.src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/Anthropoides_paradisea1.ogg";
    vid.autoplay = false;
    vid.loop = true;
    vid.addEventListener("canplaythrough", play, false);
}
```

[Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nwellcome/wZyGm/)

This is a good resource for getting a handle on all the different media element events: http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html.